# DateTime property not accepting ToShortDateString

Tags: c#

I have a property in the code something like this:

```
public Nullable<DateTime> WorkDate
```

so some place in the code I was trying to use `ToShortDateString` on it but it doesn't even show such a method in the VS IDE. Why? What is making it different from a normal `System.DataTime` type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Nullable DateTime (also known as `DateTime?`) 'hides' a `DateTime` in its .Value

So you'd want

> WorkDate.Value.ToShortDateString();

Note that since Nullable DateTimes can be null - if its null the above will crash, so either use the `??` operator, or check that it `.HasValue;`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
WorkDate.Value.ToShortDateString();
```

You may want to null check it before doing this as to defend against a null reference exception (or check `WorkDate.HasValue`).

Answer (score 2):

Use `WorkDate.Value.ToShortDateString();`

Answer (score 1):

You are going to want to access the `Value` of the Nullable

try this code

```
if(WorkDate.HasValue)
{
    WorkDate.Value.ToShortDateString();
}
```